# Removing Search Tab in Media Browser for a field

Tags: experience-editor, content-editor, media-library

When I click 'Browse' on my image field and start selecting an image in Media Browser (Sitecore 8.2) I see two tabs: Search and Browse.

I have already restricted my image field to point to a very specific folder. The Search tab doesn't make any sense here.

How do I remove the search tab completely? I don't want this global solution:
`<override xmlControl="Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Media.MediaBrowser" with="/sitecore/client/Sitecore/Common/Dialogs/SelectMediaViaTreeDialog" />`

[image]

It's for one field only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you disabled SPEAK UI and using Sheer UI.

If you want to make different UI based on what item or field you are working on, you would need to create another class for MediaBrowerForm and replace with original one at the form layout.

The class you need to take a look at is `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Media.MediaBrowser.MediaBrowserForm` at `Sitecore.Client` assembly. Mostly, you might copy the code and add the condition for the item or field you want to hide the tab.

Then, go to `MediaBrowser.xml` file at `\Website\sitecore\shell\Applications\Media\MediaBrowser` and update `CodeBeside` with the namespace.class and assembly name. You might need to update layout if needs.